# What happened to tzdata-java in Xenial 16.04?

Tags: java, development, timezone

On upgrading to xenial, the package tzdata-java was removed and is indeed no longer available. I managed to install older JDK versions (still needed for some development) from the openjdk-r PPA, but tzdata-java isn't in there either. I have seen some unit tests fail because the timezone data isn't available.

Why was tzdata-java removed, and more importantly, how can I install some kind of reasonably up-to-date timezone information for Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tzdata-java` was removed because OpenJDK 8 does not provide the necessary files to build it. Quoting the [Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814073) which prompted its removal:

> The problem is that the default java has recently been switched to openjdk-8, which doesn't provide javazic.jar. As such we can't build tzdata-java anymore.

The [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/797697/256317) gives a PPA which provides a Xenial `tzdata-java` package for OpenJDK 6 and 7.

Answer (score 6):

Java 6 and 7 timezone data were included via the `tzdata-java` package but this package isn't available for Ubuntu 16.04 so if your java version is 7 or 6 just run :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:justinludwig/tzdata
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tzdata-java
```

For more details about this PPA ,[this is it's launchpad link](https://launchpad.net/~justinludwig/+archive/ubuntu/tzdata).