# How to update daylight timezone for an app in ubuntu machine

Tags: 16.04, docker

Turkey decided to permanently stay in same time.

> DST ended on Thursday, 8 September 2016, 00:00:00. Clocks were not changed.

Turkey is between +2 and +3 UTC, so now it will stay in +3. See [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/turkey/ankara?year=2016).

[There is a discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262842/android-timezone-turkey-gmt) but I have an application in Spring Boot in an Ubuntu machine. This is how I take my date:

```
cmntWrapper.setCreatedAtString(cmnt.getCreatedAt().
now(ZoneId.of(Constants.TURKEY_ZONE)).
format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.DATE_TIME_FORMAT)));
```

This shows the time as 13.50, but it is actually 14.50, because we are in +3.

What can I do?

I dont want to use UTC +3 because they may say next year, "lets again use to +2-+3 switching to daylight saving concept". So I can't risk it.

I can't change the code in future weeks. It will stay permanent after a few weeks.

What do you suggest for permanent?

[The IANA suggests this](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html):

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar options
```

But it doesnot work:

```
root@vegan:/home/vegan/Downloads/tzdb# java -jar tzdata-latest.tar.gz Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

That is my jva

```
root@vegan:/usr/bin# whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

When I try to do in that directory

```
root@vegan:/usr/bin# java -jar tzupdater.jar -u -l http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

I got error for version and I can't install `tz`:

```
vegan@vegan:~$ sudo apt-get update 
[sudo] password for vegan:  
Hit:1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:2 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease          
Hit:3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease  
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu
xenial InRelease Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial InRelease               Ign:7
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu xenial
InRelease Hit:9 http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb beta
InRelease                   Hit:10
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                  
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial
InRelease  Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial
Release Hit:13 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64
Packages Hit:16 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial
InRelease Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main i386 Packages Ign:18
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
Translation-en_US Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main Translation-en Hit:21 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x
xenial InRelease Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata Ign:23
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64
Icons Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
amd64 Packages Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main i386 Packages Ign:18
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
Translation-en_US Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main Translation-en Ign:22
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11
Metadata Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
DEP-11 64x64 Icons Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main amd64 Packages Ign:17
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all
Packages Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
Translation-en_US Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main Translation-en Ign:22
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11
Metadata Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
DEP-11 64x64 Icons Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main amd64 Packages Ign:17
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all
Packages Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
Translation-en_US Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main Translation-en Ign:22
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11
Metadata Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
DEP-11 64x64 Icons Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main amd64 Packages Ign:17
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all
Packages Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
Translation-en_US Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main Translation-en Ign:22
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11
Metadata Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
DEP-11 64x64 Icons Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main amd64 Packages   404  Not Found Ign:17
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all
Packages Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
Translation-en_US Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu
xenial/main Translation-en Ign:22
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11
Metadata Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main
DEP-11 64x64 Icons Reading package lists... Done W: Target Packages
(main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target Translations
(main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target Translations
(main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target DEP-11
(main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target DEP-11-icons
(main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: The repository
'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not
have a Release file. N: Data from such a repository can't be
authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. N: See
apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
details. E: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been
ignored, or old ones used instead. W: Target Packages
(main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target Translations
(main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target Translations
(main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target DEP-11
(main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 W: Target DEP-11-icons
(main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list:3 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list:1 

vegan@vegan:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade tzdata tzdata-java 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done E:
Unable to locate package tzdata-java
```

also for

```
vegan@vegan:~$ sudo apt-get install tzdata-java
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tzdata-java
```

and also how can I make java? because for my test linux machine, see this please

```
puapp@PU-APP-01:~$ java -jar tzupdater.jar -u -l https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2015g.tar.gz
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So JRE is not installed but the application is up now. So, what can I do now? If I install JRE, what changes? When I run `date`, it shows the correct time already in console. I generated this app with Docker.

```
puapp@PU-APP-01:~$ java version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>


puapp@PU-APP-01:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/share/java
```

But in local I have java.

```
vegan@vegan:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

but local is not important. that linux server is immportant.

and for our main machine, there is java

```
produp@Produp-app-01:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
produp@Produp-app-01:~$
```

Now the time is 00.44. When I run

```
vegan@vegan:/usr/bin/tzdb$ date
Cum Kas  4 00:44:47 +03 2016
```

It returns the correct time, but in app the time is still 1 hour later. I don't know if always the hour was correct. If console shows true hour, what can `tzdata` do to app?

Comment: The permanent solution need to be the _tzdata_ and _tzdata-java_ package update. It is supposed to include all the changes in the political decisions in all countries. Not sure why it is not updated for Turkey, need to have a look at the package logs...

Answer (score 1):

Hh.... Usually all political decisions about timezones and DST are included in updates of the *tzdata* and  *tzdata-java* packages... So simple update of those packages need to provide the "current" political timezone...

Here is the [change log](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+changelog) for the *tzdata* and I see *New upstream release, with DST changes for Turkey (LP: #1621373)* added at 2016-10-21.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade tzdata
```

**EDITED...**

BUT!!! It appears that there is no longer tzdata-java - have a look and follow the links in the answers at [What happened to tzdata-java in Xenial 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/795901/325029) for possible workarounds via PPA.

Comment: i got errors :( i added to post the errors

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - appears that tzdata-java is removed... see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/795901/what-happened-to-tzdata-java-in-xenial-16-04 .There is a workaround via PPA.

Comment: it did not also  work http://askubuntu.com/a/797697/256317  E: Unable to locate package tzdata-java

Comment: `java -version` ?

Comment: I added to post. there is no java version coming

Comment: Maaaan.... you're giving examples from different machines... Are you sure there is no wrong terminal window involved? `sudo apt-get install default-jre ` but on _puapp@PU-APP-01:_ but for _vegan@vegan:~$_ you do have java...

Comment: and for our main machine, there is java

    java version "1.8.0_91"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

i need to test on test machine first . maybe on local first. but all of machins give true date for 'date' in console. so tzdata will change what in application? i cant figre out

Comment: Can you try again the same command with minor modification(without   "-u" )now `java -jar tzupdater.jar  -l http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz`

Comment: Fİrst i download  tzdata2016g.tar.gz then extract and go that directory where lataest.tar.gze is but it says Error: Unable to access jarfile tzupdater.jar
i tried also going to java path.  vegan@vegan:/usr/bin/tzdb$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz so i tried id  /usr/bin/ but did not work agan.

Comment: oot@vegan:/home/vegan/Downloads/tzdb# cd ../tzupdater-2.1.0/
root@vegan:/home/vegan/Downloads/tzupdater-2.1.0# java -jar tzupdater.jar -u
Using http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
Source directory does not contain file: VERSION

Comment: You got an error with tzdata2016g , probably on stackoverflow there is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832866/tzupdater-failing-with-tzdata2016g-release

Comment: and for yours, another error root@vegan:/home/vegan/Downloads/tzupdater-2.1.0# java -jar tzupdater.jar -l http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.‌​gz
Using http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.‌​gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.‌​gz